# How does this website manage to avoid its content being copied and how to copy its content

Tags: website

I would like to copy the article in this webpage http://propercloth.com/how-to-wash-a-dress-shirt.
However it won't copy in either Firefox or Chrome under my Ubuntu 12.04.

I wonder how this website manages to do that, and how I can copy the content?

Comment: Why do you want to "copy the article"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is using a Javascript to prevent users from selecting text on their site. If you are curious you can view the script [here](http://propercloth.com/js/ban_copy.js).

The easiest way around it is to just temporarily disable Javascript ([Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages#w_enabling-and-disabling-javascript), [Chrome](http://browsers.about.com/od/googlechrome/ss/disable-javascript-chrome-windows_2.htm)).